# UINavigationBar Above UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I'm programmatically creating a `UITableViewController` class that shows a table view with a simple navigation bar (though without a `UINavigationController`, as there are no further levels to the table view hierarchy).

Here is the relevant code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    UINavigationBar *navBar =  [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 44.0f)];
    [self.tableView addSubview:navBar];
}
```

However, the navigation bar covers most of the first table view cell, and scrolls with the whole view.

How can I fixate the navigation bar above the table view, and keep it from scrolling through code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using UITableViewController. Switch to a standard UIViewController, add the tableview delegate and datasource methods, point the tableview to those methods, and then you do what you want to do. You could also add a UIToolbar in the XIB and create it that way if you wish.

If you really want a navigation bar, then use an NSNavigationView controller.

Comment: what if you don't want any navigation though?

Comment: This will not work for static cells for `UITableView`. I have to use `UITableViewController` only, I tried with `UIViewController` but no luck. It requires.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a navigation controller, it takes care of this for you, but the navigation bar is just another subview.  The remedy is to frame your table view relative to the navigation bar.

```
self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0,myNavBar.frame.size.height, 320, self.view.frame.size.height-myNavBar.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: Thanks again. Oddly, the navigation bar is simply being pushed down along with the table view, still covering it. I've put the code within the viewDidLoad method, before [super viewDidLoad].

Comment: It's 44px tall TODAY. It may not be tomorrow. Apple reserves the right to change the height to 43px or 42px or 100px at their discretion. Plus the Nav Bar isn't 44px tall in Landscape mode, so you would lose out there, too.

Comment: Not sure what motivated me to add a dumb suggestion about constants to the otherwise okay answer.  Will edit.

Comment: This works great. I had a headerView (.xib file) set up for my TableViewController. The headerView had buttons on it. What I added the tableViewController into a navigation controller, the nav bar covered the response area for the buttons, causing you to push the button and having nothing happen. Resizing the frame solved this issue

Answer (score 0):

**Set the navigation bar's translucent property to NO:**

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

Answer (score -1):

Having a hierarchy of data doesn't really drive whether or not you need to use a UINavigationController. There are three good reasons to go ahead and just use the UINavigationController.

1. You get the Navigation Bar for free, and the Nav Controller handles setting the proper frame of your root view controller when you set the nav controller's root view controller property to your view controller
2. If you one day wake up and say, "Hey! I want to add another layer of information to my awesome app!", you don't need to make any changes to the overall design (or, at most, minimal ones).
3. As my comment to @danh's suggestion implies, you're immune to whatever whacky changes Apple may decide to do with regards to nav bar height.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Problem is, I'm trying to incorporate the view into a SNPopupView. I'm using ARC, and I tried just creating all of this through a nib file, only to get a whole bunch of wacky errors. I'm not sure I can incorporate the navigation controller through code in a way that works with the popup, but I'll try again.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with SNPopupView. What were the errors? Is SNPopupView what you want to have a navigation bar?

Comment: Its annoying to have to embed all modal view controllers is a nav controller

Answer (score -1):

The solution to this behavior would be to add the UINavigationBar to the Parent View Controller's view:

```
[self.parentViewController.view addSubview:myNavBar];
```

Comment: UIViewController shown modally does not have a self.parentViewController